# global variable usage

Tags: python

I have one basic question,I am declaring xmlfile as global in xml function,can I use it in another subroutine without any issues?does the order of subroutines matter?

```
 def xml():

        global xmlfile
        file = open('config\\' + productLine + '.xml','r')
        xmlfile=file.read()
 def table():
            parsexml(xmlfile)
```

Comment: ya,right,that was just a sample code..edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which the functions are written does not matter. 
The value of `xmlfile` will be determined by the order in which the functions are called.

However, it is generally better to avoid reassigning values to globals inside of functions -- it makes analyzing the behavior of functions more complicated. It is better to use function arguments and/or return values, (or perhaps use a class and make the variable a class attribute):

```
def xml():
    with open('config\\' + productLine + '.xml','r') as f:
        return f.read()

def table():
     xmlfile = xml()
     parsexml(xmlfile)
```

Comment: +1. ``global``s are almost always the wrong solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I completely agree with the other comments about avoiding global variables. You should start by redesigning to avoid them. But to answer your question:

The order of definitions of the subroutine doesn't matter, the order in which you call them does:

```
>>> def using_func():
...   print a
... 
>>> using_func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in using_func
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
>>> def defining_func():
...   global a
...   a = 1
... 
>>> using_func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in using_func
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
>>> defining_func()
>>> using_func()
1
```